# Puppeteer Question: I'm Screenshotting A Series of Pages. Can I Use Each Page URL as the Image Name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a problem with a Puppeteer script I'm writing. I've gotten it to do 90% of what it needs to do, which is use the sitemap page for any given site and go to each page before taking a full-page screenshot. It also spits out a console.log of a massive array with all of the site URLs. What I *need* to do and can't get right is to pull the page URL for each page it opens during its for loop and use that as the name for the screenshot. So like if it goes to google.com, picture 1 is called "google.com/.png", then "google.com/dogpictures.png" etc.

I'm including it below, I'd love to hear any feedback:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
    'use strict'
 
    const smta = require('sitemap-to-array')
    const options = { returnOnComplete: true}
    const sitemapUrl = 'https:____.org/page-sitemap.xml'
     
    smta(sitemapUrl, options, (error, list) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error)
      } else {     

        console.log(list)
        useSitemapWithPuppeteer(list);
      }
    })

  const useSitemapWithPuppeteer = async (array) => {  

  const urls = array.map(obj => obj.loc);
  
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,
  });
  
  for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {  
    const url = urls[i];
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
    await page.goto(`${url}`, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
    const currentURL = page.url;
    await page.screenshot({ path: "test" + i + ".png", fullPage: true });
    
  }
  await browser.close();
  
}})();
```

Comment: Well there's the question for most high-end developments how many files can sit within a directory without causing havoc and that number is quite high but some say don't go crazy with 10,000+ files in a single directory. Beyond that your naming scheme is up to you and what makes sense.

Comment: Also depends on if you require security around these images, in such case you'd name them uniquely so those intended to have the information have it or it'd take millions of guesses to find it by a spider bot.

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback. Yeah, this is a one-off project and will only generate around 170 pictures at the max, so we should be fine on that accont. I don't need much in the way of security, this is for private use so it literally just needs to be [screenshot of https://www.page1.com | Title: url(https://www.page1.com).png]

From what I have here, is there any way you could help me achieve this?